# How to get all terminal service sessions?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019, terminal-services

On Windows Server 2019, I am comparing the users connected in the task manager, what I get from the `query user` (or shortcut `quser`) command from the command line and finally what I see with the performance counters in the Performance Monitor utility.

Here is my issue: I am connected with RDP, so in the task manager and command line utility I do see my RDP section active. However, when looking at performance counters, I see 1 active session and 2 inactive sessions for a total of 3 sessions. Emphasis in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot evidence]

What are the supposedly 2 inactive terminal service sessions that I can't see in the task manager and in the command line? How can I find what it is?

Comment: If you reboot the server, and yes I understand what I am asking, are the inactive sessions cleared?

Comment: @Ramhound Your question does totally make sense. Rebooting the server from the console didn't clear the sessions, they're still there and showing up as inactive.

Comment: My conclusion would be those sessions would be internal to the server and/or the 3.000 is an just a scale value.  Other than the performance monitor can you find any evidence those sessions actual existed?

Comment: @Ramhound Performance counters (winperf) report the same as the Performance Monitor and is used by my monitoring server but other than that, no, I couldn't find anything. I'm just curious what it is exactly since I can't just arbitrary substract 2 sessions without knowing what it is.